# Sort Programs in StartMenu

Tags: windows, start-menu

Is there a way to (alphabetically or in other way) to sort program list in the Start=>Programs menu?

When installing / uninstalling programs this menu is added-removed, but not sorted, and sometimes takes time to find a nested program in this list.

I have Windows XP, but think the same situation could be applied and on the other versions of Windows.

Comment: Are you talking about the most-used list that appears upon clicking the Start button, or are you talking about the all programs menu?

Comment: I don't use "Most used", but classic program list.

Comment: Won't apply to Vista and later versions of Windows as those auto-sort the list (if you're using it at all; I don't think of a sensible reason to do so, given the search box, though).

Comment: Your image is broken. Do you have the original that you could reupload? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XP:
Right-click on any item in the "programs" list, and select "Sort by name"

[image: (Sort by name image)]

Later versions of windows:
Automatically sorted by name

Comment: see updated image. Only Open and Explore commands available.

Comment: @serhio - you have to click on an element **inside** the programs, not on "programs" directly.

Comment: @Gnoupi: I need to sort programs, not a program. I find the solution, see my answer.

Comment: Ah, OK, undertstood. give the same result as my solution. your image is not very comprehensible however.